# Will any network participant be able to send to a native segwit address?

Tags: segregated-witness

Does a wallet have to upgrade to send to a native segwit address provided by the recipient or can anyone send to them, as was the case with the P2SH-wrapped segwit addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [compatibility section of BIP-0173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#Compatibility), it states:

> Only new software will be able to use these addresses, and only for receivers with segwit-enabled new software. In all other cases, P2SH or P2PKH addresses can be used.